# Separating data by a particular cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to improve some code I did not write, mostly to make it easier for other people to understand (I found it to be really weirdly written). I attempted to rewrite it, and it does basically the same thing, using roughly the same processes.

However, the old one takes about 2 minutes to run with some data I recorded. The other takes *well* over an hour to work on the same data. What on earth is going on?

The data format they work on is:

[image: Sample Data]

I should add: I would use dictionaries, as I think they would be fastest, except the number of "TextX" is basically random. Sometimes only Text1 appears.  Sometimes it goes all the way to Text20, or more.

Old code:

> ```
> sub DivideSheet()
> Application.ScreenUpdating = False
>
> Dim name As String
> Dim point_name As String
> Dim SheetCount, sheetNumber As Integer
> Dim RowCount, RowStart As Long
> Dim Exist, RowEmpty As Boolean
>
> Sheets("RAW DATA").Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
>     FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(27, 1), _
>     Array(31, 1), Array(36, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
>
> Exist = False
> RowCount = 1
> RowStart = 1
> SheetCount = 1
> point_name = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 3)
>
> For RowCount = 1 To 1048576                                       'loop through all the rows in the sheet
>
>     If CStr(Sheets(1).Cells(RowCount, 3)) = "" Then             'If the cell isnt a new transmition
>                                                                 'do nothing
>     ElseIf CStr(Sheets(1).Cells(RowCount, 3)) = point_name Then   'If the new transmition is from the same node
>                                                                 'Do nothing
>     Else                                                        'If its a new node
>
>         For SheetCount = 1 To Sheets.Count                      'loop through sheets
>
>             If Worksheets(SheetCount).name = point_name Then      'If the sheet name matches point_name
>                 Exist = True                                    'set flag to true
>                 sheetNumber = SheetCount                        'Record Sheet number
>                 Exit For                                        'Exit the for loop
>             End If
>
>         Next SheetCount
>
>         If Exist = False Then                                   'If the Node didnt have a sheet
>             sheetNumber = SheetCount
>             Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(SheetCount - 1)    'Create a sheet
>             Worksheets(Sheets.Count).name = point_name            'Name it for the RTU
>         End If
>
>         Call CopyLine(sheetNumber, RowStart, RowCount - 1)      'Call the Copying function to copy the chunk of data
>
>         RowStart = RowCount                                     'Set a new start point for the next chunk of data
>
>         point_name = Worksheets(1).Cells(RowCount, 3)             'Set the Node the chunk of data will belong to
>
>         SheetCount = 1                                          'Reset Variable
>         Exist = False                                           'Reset Variable
>
>
>     End If
>
> Next RowCount
>
> SheetCount = 1                                                  'Resets the SheetCount Variable
>
>
> For SheetCount = 1 To Sheets.Count                              'Loops through Sheets
>
>     Sheets(SheetCount).Columns("H:H").EntireColumn.AutoFit      'Autofits the H column
>
> Next SheetCount
>
> End Sub
>
> Public Sub CopyLine(sheetNumber As Integer, RowStart As Long, rowNumber As Long)
>
>     If Sheets(sheetNumber).Range("A1").Value = "" Then           'If its the first data to enter the sheet
>                                                                     'Copy the chunk of data
>         Sheets(1).Range("a" & RowStart, "h" & rowNumber).Copy _
>         Destination:=Sheets(sheetNumber).Range("A1", Cells(rowNumber - RowStart + 1, "H"))
>
>     ElseIf Sheets(sheetNumber).Range("H2").Value = "" Then       'If its the Second data to enter the sheet
>                                                                     'Copy the chunk of data
>         Sheets(1).Range("a" & RowStart, "h" & rowNumber).Copy _
>         Destination:=Sheets(sheetNumber).Range("A2", Cells(rowNumber - RowStart + 2, "H"))
>
>     Else                                                            'otherwise
>                                                                     'Copy the chunk of data
>        Sheets(1).Range("a" & RowStart, "h" & rowNumber).Copy _
>        Destination:=Sheets(sheetNumber).Range("h1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -7)
>
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```

My code:

```
sub DivideSheet()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Point As String

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

wb1.Sheets("RAW DATA").Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(27, 1), _
    Array(31, 1), Array(36, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

'loop through all the rows in the sheet
For i = 1 To wb1.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Point = wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
    If wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then
        a = sheetexists(Point)
            If a Then
                Call CopyLine(a, i, Point)
            Else
                wb1.Sheets.Add after:=wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count).name = Point
                Call CopyLine(wb1.Sheets.Count, i, Point)
                wb1.Sheets(Sheets.Count).Rows(1).Delete
            End If
    End If
Next i

For Each wsh In wb1.Sheets              'Loops through Sheets
    wsh.Columns.AutoFit         'Autofits everything
Next wsh

End Sub

Public Sub CopyLine(a, i, Point)

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
j = i + 1
While (wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 3) = "" Or wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 3) = Point) And j <= wb1.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count 'WorksheetFunction.CountA(wb1.Sheets(1).Rows(i)) = 0
    j = j + 1
Wend

wb1.Sheets(1).Range(wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1), wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(j - 1, 8)).Copy Destination:=wb1.Sheets(a).Cells(wb1.Sheets(a).UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(1, 0)
i = j - 1
End Sub

Function sheetexists(ByVal Point As String) As Long
Dim a As Integer
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

sheetexists = 0
For a = 1 To wb1.Sheets.Count
    If wb1.Sheets(a).name = Point Then
        sheetexists = a
        Exit Function
    End If
Next a

End Function
```

I'm not crazy, right? Is there no fundamental difference between these two, other than mine being fewer lines, less circuitous, and generally not being wasteful? So why is my new code taking so much longer?

Comment: [Cross-posted from Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41964828/1188513)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple places in your code where you've "de-optimized".  I'm not sure which of these adds up to a hour of run-time, but these are the most egregious:

---

Removing variable declarations makes them implicitly `Variant`.  The following are undeclared in `DivideSheet()`:  `wb1`, `i`, `a`, and `wsh`.  This is a *huge* performance penalty, because every time you use them, the underlying values need to be coerced out of the `Variant`.  You also can't store strongly typed objects in a `Variant`, so that means every single one of your calls to `wb1` and `wsh` is late-bound instead of early-bound (that's why you don't get any Intellisense when you type `wb1.` or `wsh.`.  That's a *ton* of needless overhead, especially when you're in a loop. If you can early-bind, do it. Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, and then declare everything. Put the strong typing back in.

Note that the original code had this wrong too - lines like...

> ```
> Dim RowCount, RowStart As Long
> ```

...only type the last variable as `Long` - the rest are `Variant`.

---

You also removed the strong typing from `CopyLine`.  In the old code, it's declared as:

> ```
> Public Sub CopyLine(sheetNumber As Integer, RowStart As Long, rowNumber As Long)
> ```

You have it as `Public Sub CopyLine(a, i, Point)`, which means that all of the parameters are implicitly `Variant`.  Granted, you're basically using `Variant` for *everything*, but again, you just added *at least* 3 extra unboxings for *every call*.  Not to mention the extra work that Excel needs to do when you pass them as indexers to `Cells`.  Put the strong typing back in.

---

You created implicit casts when you extracted the `sheetexists` function.  You have it declared as returning a `Long`, but you declare `a` as `Integer` and then return that with `sheetexists = a`. Then when you call it here...

> ```
> a = sheetexists(Point)
> ```

...you coerce it into a `Variant` (`a` is undeclared in `DivideSheet`), then on the next line you treat is as a `Boolean`...

> ```
> If a Then
> ```

...before passing it (as a `Variant`) to `CopyLine`, where it gets used as a `Variant` of subtype `Integer` again:  `Sheets(a)`.  (Whew!).  Put the... wait for it... strong typing back in.

---

You forgot `wb1` when you extracted the `sheetexists` function.  You have `Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook` at the top of `DivideSheet`...and the repeat that call at the top of both `sheetexists` *and* `CopyLine`.  If you want to make the 2 functions a bit more reusable, give them a Workbook parameter and pass that in. If you don't care, skip the variable declaration all together and just use `ThisWorkbook` explicitly.  Note that this *isn't* the same as `ActiveWorkbook` - it's a hard reference to the `ThisWorkbook` class in the project the code is in.

---

The original code cached the result of the call to `Sheets.Count`.  This code only calls `Sheets.Count` *once* when it set up the loop:

> ```
>     For SheetCount = 1 To Sheets.Count                      'loop through sheets
>
>         If Worksheets(SheetCount).name = point_name Then      'If the sheet name matches point_name
>             Exist = True                                    'set flag to true
>             sheetNumber = SheetCount                        'Record Sheet number
>             Exit For                                        'Exit the for loop
>         End If
>
>     Next SheetCount
>
>     If Exist = False Then                                   'If the Node didnt have a sheet
>         sheetNumber = SheetCount
>         Worksheets.Add after:=Worksheets(SheetCount - 1)    'Create a sheet
>         Worksheets(Sheets.Count).name = point_name            'Name it for the RTU
>     End If
> ```

Your code calls it 4 times every time you add a sheet. You actually don't even need it in the loop ***at all***, because if you don't end up with `Sheets.Count + 1` worksheets after you call `Sheets.Add`, then there is something very seriously wrong (this is a problem in the original code too). Cache values that you need to reuse.

---

Getting back to `CopyLine`, your code isn't equivalent at *all*. The original function is actually pretty efficient at what it does - it calculates what it needs to copy, then does that in a single operation. Your code doesn't perform a calculation at all - it counts row by row with this code (line continuations added for clarity):

> ```
> While (wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 3) = "" Or _
>        wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 3) = Point) And _
>        j <= wb1.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
>     j = j + 1
> Wend
> ```

VBA doesn't short circuit the calls, so first you get the value of `Cells(j, 3)` (implicitly) twice, compare it to two different things, and (then this is the huge one) get the exact same value for `wb1.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count` every time through the loop.  Again, cache values that you need to reuse. This is much easier if you use a `Do` loop (there isn't an `Exit While` statement):

```
Dim rowCount As Long
rowCount = wb1.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
Do While j <= rowCount
    Dim cellValue As Variant
    cellValue = wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 3)
    If cellValue = vbNullString Or cellValue = Point Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    j = j + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Huh.  So I thought I was making it easier to read, and little did I know - I destroyed it!  I had no idea using a variant was such a big deal, or making it recalculate everything would slow it down so much.  Also, for CopyLine, I tried to make it so that it would basically split up the two countings - it counts to the new `Point` in `sub DivideSheet` and to where it has to copy in `sub CopyLine`, and updates it's record as it goes - I thought it would be easier for someone later to look at this and understand on first glance what was going on.  [1]

Comment: I will make these fixes and see how it goes.  And thank you! [2]

Comment: @GrahamPerry - To be honest, even without the comments, I thought the original code was much easier to understand what it was doing.  I'd probably fix the performance issues with the *original* and leave it at that.

Comment: If I may be so bold as to ask another question: I don't understand how `CopyLine` is so different between the two functions, really.  The original code loops through every line, and I loop through every line - I just do half the counting in `DivideSheet` and half of it in `CopyLine` (so I guess my specific function is quite different but the net effect I thought was identical).  The logic is identical - if you see nothing or `Point`, carry on, otherwise, copy.  Or at least that's what I thought.  What am I missing?

Comment: @GrahamPerry - It's a nested loop.  The original code finds the range to copy by *calculating* `rowNumber - RowStart`. The new code usies a `While` loop. The outer loop (in `DivideSheet`) calls `CopyLine`, which runs an inner loop.  The original code doesn't loop inside `CopyLine`.

Answer (score 3):

Before changing anything functionality-wise, I usually like to layout things and improve the readability. The single, most impactful thing that could have been done, would have been to add an indentation level for every scope.

So instead of this:

```
Sub DoSomething(bar)
Dim foo
foo = 42
If bar > foo Then
    DoSomethingElse
End If
End Sub
```

You would have that:

```
Sub DoSomething(bar)
    Dim foo
    foo = 42
    If bar > foo Then
        DoSomethingElse
    End If
End Sub
```

That way it's **much** easier to tell where procedures start and end, *especially* when there's vertical whitespace between [groups of] statements (which is a very good thing!).

The next thing to do, to improve readability, is to refactor/rename the variables so that they have *meaningful names*. Now, doing that is *theoretically* innocuous - but in practice doing it without proper tooling (Ctrl+H?) can do real annoying damage, and doing it by hand is tedious and error-prone.

I, along with a number of other [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) reviewers on this site (answerers on Stack Overflow, too), have developped [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/) (an ongoing, open-source VBE add-in project), specifically built to assist in these kinds of things (including indentation):

[image: Rubberduck's refactor/rename tool]

The next thing I'd look for, is for Rubberduck's inspection results. These things range from minor readability improvement suggestions to serious code quality issues.

You can run inspection results online by pasting your code in the box at the bottom of [this page](http://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/List) (it's *much* faster in the actual VBE though).

Here are a few:

- **Use of 'Call' statement**

  *The 'Call' statement is no longer required to call procedures, and only exists in the language to support legacy code that required it; it can be safely rewritten to an implicit call.*

  So this:

  > ```
  > Call CopyLine(a, i, Point)
  > ```

  Could be written like this:

  ```
   CopyLine a, i, Point
  ```
- **Implicit 'Variant' variables**

  *A variable whose type isn't explicitly declared, is implicitly 'Variant'. Consider making it an explicit 'Variant' if that's intended, or declare a more specific type.*

  This applies to the parameters in the signature of the `CopyLine` procedure:

  > ```
  > Public Sub CopyLine(a, i, Point)
  > ```

  Could be written like this:

  ```
   Public Sub CopyLine(ByVal a As Long, ByVal i As Long, ByVal Point As String)
  ```
- **Implicity public member**

  *Module members are public by default, which can be counter-intuitive. Consider specifying explicit access modifiers to avoid ambiguity.*

  Procedure `DivideSheet` and function `sheetexists` are both implicitly `Public`, and it while `CopyLine` is explicitly `Public`, if it's only ever called from `DivideSheet` then it should be `Private`. Proper scoping/visibility ensures a cleaner API, especially with larger projects.
- **Implicit references to ActiveSheet/ActiveWorkbook**

  *Implicit references to the active sheet/workbook make the code frail and harder to debug. Consider making these references explicit when they're intended, and prefer working off object references.*

  Whenever you use an *unqualified* `Range` or `Sheets` call, you're calling a member of the hidden `_Global` module, and your code implicitly works off the `ActiveSheet`. This affects the destination `Range("A1")` on line 9, and the `Sheets.Count` calls in lines 22, 23 and 25.

  Also worth noting, if you intend to work with `Worksheet` objects, then don't query the `Sheets` collection; use the `Worksheets` collection instead - `Sheets` can return with a `Chart` object, and a chart doesn't have a `UsedRange` member; that would blow up at run-time with error 438. Of course it doesn't "really" matter if your workbook doesn't have chart sheets, but the very moment it does, your code breaks. Best use the `Worksheets` collection.
- **Use meaningful names**

  *Identifier names should indicate what they're used for and should be readable; avoid disemvoweling, numeric suffixes, and 1-2 character names.*

  Identifiers `wb1`, `a`, `wsh`, and arguably `i` and `j` could all use better, more descriptive names.
- **Empty string literal**

  *The built-in constant 'vbNullString' is a null string pointer taking up 0 bytes of memory, that unambiguously conveys the intent of an empty string.*

  Instead of comparing to `""`, compare to `vbNullString`.

Now, these are nice, *sometimes* problematic, but somewhat superficial observations. The code has more serious issues:

- **'Option Explicit' is not specified**

  *VBA will happily compile a typo: use 'Option Explicit' to prevent successfully compiling an erroneous program.*

  I cannot stress this one enough. **ALWAYS. USE. OPTION. EXPLICIT.** Countless bugs and Stack Overflow questions could have been avoided, by simply typing these two words at the top of every module.
- **Undeclared variables**

  *Code that uses undeclared variables does not compile when Option Explicit is specified. Undeclared variables are always Variant, a data type that incurs unnecessary overhead and storage.*

  Local variables `wb1`, `i`, `a`, and `wsh` aren't declared in `DivideSheet`; local variables `wb1` and `j` aren't declared in `CopyLine`, and `wb1` isn't declared in `sheetexists`.

I like that you've fixed these:

> ```
> Dim SheetCount, sheetNumber As Integer
> Dim RowCount, RowStart As Long
> Dim Exist, RowEmpty As Boolean
> ```

Having multiple declarations in the same instructions sets you up for a common beginner trap: *every single variable needs an explicit type*. I'm pretty sure the author thinks they've declared both `Exist` and `RowEmpty` as `Boolean` variables (and `SheetCount` would be an `Integer`, and `RowCount` a `Long`), but `SheetCount`, `RowCount` and `Exist` are all implicit `Variant`, because their declaration is missing the `As` clause.

---

Just a quick note about casing & consistency: in VBA, public identifiers should be `PascalCase`, and locals/parameters should be `camelCase`. The code isn't consistent about it, and that can be distracting.

Another note, about comments: good comments say *why*, not *what*. Comments that merely state the obvious, or outright repeat verbatim what the code already says, are useless and should be removed.

Like this one:

> ```
> 'loop through all the rows in the sheet
> For i = 1 To wb1.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
> ```

And these:

> ```
> For Each wsh In wb1.Sheets          'Loops through Sheets
>     wsh.Columns.AutoFit     'Autofits everything
> ```

---

`DivideSheets` is doing quite a number of things - I'd extract more methods out of it - but this is worrying:

> ```
> Application.DisplayAlerts = False
> Application.ScreenUpdating = False
> ```

It's never turned back on! Consider also switching `Application.Calculation` to `XlCalculationManual`, to avoid having Excel perform useless automatic calculations ...but *don't forget to toggle it back to automatic when you're done!*

---

I have to agree, there's something outrageous about taking a piece of code that completes in two minutes, and then seeing it take well over an hour to do the same thing after you've changed it a bit.

I'll leave the actual performance review to other reviewers... for now :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that this is one part of a set of macros.  `wb1` is declared (publicly) in the code for a userform as workbook; likewise, `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` are present, just not in this particular module.  Regardless, thank you.  I made the adjustments that you suggested.

Comment: If you're toggling on ScreenUpdating and DisplayAlerts in a different scope than where you're toggling it off, then it's definitely confusing. wb1 does not need to be global at all either.

Comment: @GrahamPerry just noticed... if `wb1` is declared publicly in a form's code-behind, when you do `Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook` in `DivideSheet` you are **NOT** referring to the `wb1` variable in the form's code-behind, because a form is an object, so you would have to qualify it with `MyAwesomeForm.wb1` to access it. In other words, `wb1` *is* an undeclared variable here...